# Pan Canadian Strahler Order stream data

Tags: geospatial, canada

I am working with the CanVec series linear_flow spatial data set, however, it doesn't have the strahler order value attached to the stream/river segments.  Is there a pan Canadian strahler order spatial data set out there that is routable i.e. has the direction of flow for each stream ?